# Unable to download PDF in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, iis

I have created a method that creates and saves a pdf to a directory in the project. I am unable to get this file to download after it is created however. I have tried several options i have seen on stack overflow, and numerous other sites. I can see PDF content in the response in firebug, and i can open the file manually, but no file download. Please help.

Controller

```
    public class SignatureController : Controller
    {
    // GET: Signature
    public FileContentResult Index(string orderNumber)
    {
        var pdfFile = DocumentGenerator.GenerateSignedDocument(orderNumber);

        byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFile);
        string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(pdfFile);

        System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = pdfFile,
            Inline = true,
        };

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

        return File(filedata, contentType);
    }
}
```

PDF Generator

```
        public static string GenerateSignedDocument(string orderNumber)
        {

      ...............

        string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy");

        string fileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(pdfTempPath) + orderNumber + currentDate + ".pdf";

        pdfDocument.Save(fileName);
        return fileName;
    }
```

Header is returning

Cache-Control
private
Content-Disposition 
attachment; filename="signed document.pdf"
Content-Encoding
gzip
Content-Type
application/pdf
Date
Thu, 16 Jul 2015 16:58:29 GMT
Server
Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Transfer-Encoding
chunked
Vary
Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version
4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 
5.2
X-Powered-By
ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles
=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNccmphbWVzXFNvdXJjZVxXb3Jrc3BhY2VzXEN1c3RvbWVyUGlja1VwXEN1c3RvbWVyUGlja1VwLldlYlxTaWduYXR1cmVcSW5kZXg
=?=

Answer (score 0):

Set [`Inline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contentdisposition.inline(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false` or omit it. That way the the header is `attachment` (instead of `inline`).

e.g (this sample downloads a file in file system)

```
public FilePathResult DownloadPdf()
{
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "foo.pdf"
        //Inline = false //false or omit
    };


    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File("~/files/somefile.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

The header will look like: `Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=foo.pdf`

---

File name is what you set - sample is obtaining a pdf from file system only because I don't generate one on the fly (so your code is fine for `byte` result). The key item is to return the correct header `attachment` - you can even set that manually

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfFile);
```

and not have to use `System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition`. BTW, is your `pdfFile` variable a string (you're using that as the `FileName` property)?

Hth...

Comment: still no go. Does the FileName need to be the exact name of the file, or just what you want it to say. I am able to open the document locally if if put     Process.Start(pdfFile); locally, but not when deployed to iis

Comment: @Rickjames see update - I suspect something's up with your `pdfFile` variable - you're setting that as the **file name** (but I can see you're doing `ReadAllBytes` on it)

Comment: still no luck...see the update for what the header is returning.